# Does someone know why I am asking to security check?

Tags: security

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 without an antivirus. I am using google chrome for internet browsing. I am frequently having a page saying that:

> One more step Please complete the security check to access www.example.com

[image]

Would you please let me know why this page and how to get rid of that.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can someone tell me why down voting this question? Is it unclear or not useful?

Comment: @SiddiquiNoor I didn't downvote, but I think it's because we can't tell you anything useful without knowing what web site is producing the message. Also, questions about specific web apps/sites are off-topic here.

Comment: Only the down voter can say you why... for me it's an honest question even if you can try to give an example page from where it cames out... probably it is a pop up advertisement from another page. Use add on like adblock or ghostery to get rid of it. And set in the options to ask or to block pop up windows...

Comment: @BenN I am not asking for any specific web apps/sites. It comes for other sites too. That was an example.

Comment: @Hastur It is not a pop up advertisement. I will use adblock or ghostery, thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not a security check for you. It's a captcha that the website uses to verify that you are a human being and not a bot. A captcha (an acronym for "Completely Automated Public Turing test to tell Computers and Humans Apart") is a type of challenge-response test used in computing to determine whether or not the user is human. A human being would be able to read the captcha, but the captcha might be visually complicated enough to stop some bots from entering the site.

If there was a way to easily get rid of or bypass the captcha, then it would defeat the purpose of the captcha, which is to protect the website from being accessed by bots.

Comment: My concern is I am not getting this every time on a particular website. As for example I had to complete the captcha today for http://stackexchange.com/, not everytime, do you have it for http://stackexchange.com/ ever. So I am in doubt that whether I have infected with any virus or malware that signals the site to verify me as a human.

Comment: I get a captcha on http://stackexchange.com/ every time I copy an answer from a draft text file on my local file system to a question or answer and click the Post button to submit it. If I edit it even by changing one character before I post it, then I don't get the captcha.

Comment: Well understood that it's normal, I am getting same captcha page for other sites though, I meant same page as everything same without the captcha number, which is very normal. So is it that StackExchange or any other company getting captcha support from the same.

Comment: While captchas may look the same on different sites, there is not always a way to prove that it is the same code behind the captcha running on different sites, because the code may be executed on the server where it's impossible to view its source code from your computer, instead of it being executed locally by your web browser.

Comment: *every time I copy an answer from a draft text file on my local file system to a question or answer*. Of course. You start editing and within 3 seconds you click OK to save that entire text. That's exactly the behaviour the website sees when an automatic scripts tries to dump its spam garbage.